# ICO0005E: A communication error occurred during sending or receiving the IMS message. java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websphere, websphere-liberty, ims

I'm connecting to IMS ST server by using the below config and it works fine:-

```
 <connectionFactory  id="ims" jndiName="eis/IMSSyncNonPersistent">
<properties.imsico91025a dataStoreName="st.datastoreName" hostName="st.hostname" portNumber="st.portnumber"/>
  </connectionFactory>
```

but when I use the same config in ET it gives the above mentioned error. To solve it I used the below config after looking up the error on IBM documentation about purge policy:-

```
ICO0005E SocketException is thrown when:
A Java client attempts to use a connection for which the underlying socket is no longer connected to IMS Connect. The socket connection might be lost if IMS Connect is recycled, but the application server is not. After IMS Connect is restarted, the connections that were formerly successfully connected to IMS Connect are still in the connection pool. As clients attempt to reuse each of these connections, the exception java.net.SocketException is thrown, and the connection object is removed from the connection pool.
You can change this behavior in WebSphere Application Server by setting the purge policy of the connection factory that is used by the Java application to the entire pool.
```

```
 <authData id="et.authalias" user="et.username" password="et.password"/>
  <connectionFactory  id="ims" authDataAlias="et.authalias" jndiName="eis/IMSSyncNonPersistent" purgePolicy="EntirePool" maxPoolSize="50">
    <properties.imsico91025a dataStoreName="et.datastore" hostName="et.hostname" portNumber="et.portnumber"/>
  </connectionFactory>
```

Didn't work. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Connection was reset because the IMS endpoint was SSL encrypted.I configured the SSL key store and trust store along with passwords and passed the credentials in the request and it started working.

Comment: Did you do that in java code? How did you add those in request? Can you please share the code ?